# Filtering duplicate rows based on multiple columns (QueryBuilder 4.2)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I've ran into a little difficulty when trying to filter top N results for a table.

Assume the following table:

```
ID, X, Y, Result0, Result1
-------------------------------
0   0  0    1         4
1   0  1    2         5
2   0  1    1         4
3   0  2    2         5
4   0  3    0         1
5   1  3    3         4
6   1  3    2         5
7   1  3    4         6
```

So, let's say I want to get the top 2 results for the highest Result0 value, using Result1 as a tie breaker if the Result0 values are equal, and having only distinct values for (X,Y),

if I'll run the following query:

```
            $result = DB::table('table')
            ->orderBy('Result1', 'DSC')
            ->orderBy('Result0', 'DSC')
            ->take(300)
            ->get();
```

This code will return IDs 5,7, because they have the highest Result0 values, but the X,Y for these fields are identical, and I'd like to get only top result for distinct X,Y values.

I tried adding a

```
->groupBy('X','Y')
```

But it grouped the entries based on the database order of the entries (i.e the ID) rather than my sorting of that table.

Anyone has any idea how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: What is your expected output can you post an example

Comment: Try selecting your column needed , before performing your orderBy function.